# get Json with Typescript and Angular

Tags: angularjs, json, typescript

I have this interfaces and this class :

```
module AnimalPlanet{
     export interface Pet {
        Type: string;
        Name: string;
        Age: string;
        Color: string;
        SpecialCare: boolean;
        AvailableForAdoption: boolean;
        LDAdoption: boolean;
        History?: string;
        featured: boolean;
        newest: boolean;
        imageUrl: string;
        type: string;
        name: string;
    }

    export interface RootObject {
        pets: Pet[];
    }

  export class petsCtrl {
        dataFromServer : RootObject;
        constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService) {
            this.$http.get('/app/pets/pets.json').then(function(response){
               console.log(response.data);
                   return response.data;

                });
        }
    }

    petsCtrl.$inject = ['$http'];
    app.controller("petsCtrl", petsCtrl);           
}
```

I try to show in view some data, but something doesn t work with my get method.Maybe my class is wrong write . Can you help me please? Thnaks!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there is something wrong. You have to assign the response from your http call to a property of your scope, not do a `return xxx`.

You Ctrl must be something like :

```js
 export class petsCtrl {
        dataFromServer : RootObject;
        constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService, private $scope: any) {
            this.$http.get('/app/pets/pets.json').then(function(response){
               console.log(response.data);
                   this.$scope.pets = response.data;

                });
        }
    }

petsCtrl.$inject = ['$http', '$scope'];
```

Then in your view, you can display the property pets :

```html
<div data-ng-bind="pets | json"></div>
```

Comment: I received a json like this:[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
Age: "5-6 years old"
AvailableForAdoption: true
Color: "brown"
History: "abandoned by owner"
LDAdoption: true
Name: "Catty"
SpecialCare: true
Type: "cat"
featured: true
imageUrl: "img/photo_latest14.jpg"
newest: true
__proto__: Object

Comment: and an error : TypeError: Cannot set property 'pets' of undefined

Comment: Sorry, you have to change the inject property :  `petsCtrl.$inject = ['$http', '$scope'];`(I update the code)

Comment: Ok. No errors for now , but in my view nothing happend.<table class="table" ng-controller="petsCtrl">
    <tr ng-repeat="pet in pets">
      <td>{{pet.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{pet.Type}}</td>
      <td>{{pet.Name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

Comment: Could you set a breakpoint in the http callback and check if there is data ? Maybe a little jsfiddle/plunkr could help :)

Comment: Here a working sample : https://jsfiddle.net/gh32amfh/1/. I removed the ngRoute part (not interesting in our case) and replace the http call by a timeout call (to emulate the delay, because I have not access to your json file). Is that ok for you ?